# "Web design" vs. "webdesign"

Tags: orthography, compounds, spacing

Suppose I want to use the word in a company's name, for example:

> - ABC Web Design
> - ABC Webdesign

Which one is correct? Should it be one word or two?

Comment: It's your company. You can call it Bew Denisg, for all I care. It's another question whether dictionaries have accepted "webdesign" yet, which they haven't.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան Obviously I can have anything as a company name, the words you are using are not general terms whereas the ones I provided are known words so it makes sense to go in a right naming ...

Comment: Never mind dictionaries, I've actually never once seen *webdesign* in the wild (except in German, of course). So much for "known words". But Armen is right, for a name it does not matter. Just because "Webdesign" doesn't exist, doesn't mean it can't be a company name.

Comment: @RegDwigнt So two separate words is a way to go? Also if I want Design"s", then I need to have two separate words...

Comment: Ok I searched a bit and [Wikipedia spells it separately](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_design)...

Comment: To be honest, my natural instinct would be to go with 'Web Design' since it seems to be more conventional and would be the only structure which would have made sense a couple of years back. Webdesign is just one of those words which has come about due to the increasing influence of technology on our everyday lives, much like 'tweets' or 'texts'. I suppose in a couple of years it will be a lot more prevalent, but again - 'Web Design' seems more professional in my opinion.

Comment: I know this is English stack, not SEO stack, but the way "web design" is trending, "ABC App and Web Design" would be correct https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=app%20design%2C%20web%20design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be much of a consensus for which is proper, but looking on the Internet, it seems that Web Design would be a better choice. According to [this source](http://webstudio2u.com/seo/373-web-design-vs-webdesign.html) (albeit written in 2011) shows that Web Design is the more popular word for search engines. In this digital age, SEO (Search Engine Optimization) is very important for a company. Using Web Design would yield more potential customers.

EDIT: I used [Google's Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=web%20design%2Cwebdesign&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cweb%20design%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwebdesign%3B%2Cc0) using the terms. As you can see, Web Design is overwhelmingly more popular than webdesign.

Answer (score 1):

## 'Webdesign' is not a word

---

You should use the form **ABC Web Design**. **Webdesign** is merely a concatenation of two words: 'web' and 'design'.

'Webdesign' is not a word. [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/webdesign) does not have this word in their database and a search on [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?client=gmail#q=definition%20of%20%22webdesign%22) returns only German words. By using the form 'webdesign' the number of visitors coming to your website from a search engine will drop as the majority of people search for **web design**.

By all means, use **ABC Web Design**.